# Is my understanding of JavaScript `this` correct?

Tags: javascript, this

Given the following snippet copied from [a well known question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236747/5290519) on this site:

```javascript
x = 9;
var module = {
    x: 81,
    getX: function () {
        return this.x;
    }
};

module.getX(); // 81

var getX = module.getX;
getX(); // 9, because in this case, "this" refers to the global object

// create a new function with 'this' bound to module
var boundGetX = getX.bind(module);
boundGetX(); // 81
```

My logic to understand this is:

- Since the (first) `getX` belongs to the `module` object, it cannot be seen without the prefix `module.`, so everyone knows that it should be `module.getX()`
- But what causes confusion is that `this` of the (first) `getX` will also reference the *pointer* calling the (first) `getX` function. I'm not sure about whether my wording is correct.
- When I define the second (*pointer* to) function by `var getX = module.getX`, it helps us to keep seeing the first `getX` inside/of `module`.

But, since most people (in the past) didn't know about the second point, i.e. the pointer used when calling the function matters, i.e.

```
// the second getX() in the above example.
getX()
// is equivalent to:
globalPointer.getX()
```

and since the global `x = 9` is belongs to the `globalPointer`, so the result is `9` instead fo `81`.

Please help me check about my understanding, either the correct wording or the **real** logic behind the scene are welcome.

Comment: `this` keyword references the object which is calling the method. If you use a global object to call a method that uses the `this` keyword, it will automatically know that `this` is the global object, so variables tied to that global object (global variables) are to be used. So, I think your understanding is correct.

Comment: this will help: [you-dont-know-js: this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the (first) `getX` belongs to the module object, it cannot be seen without the prefix `module.`, so everyone knows that it should be `module.getX()`

This is inexact. The `getX` function does not *belong* to the `module` object. Rather the `module` object has a property named `getX` which refers to the function object named `getX`. The `getX` function object has no information about where it is stored.

When the object intializer for `module` is compiled, the anonymous function value used to initialize `module.getX` is automatically named after the property being initialized. This is how the `getX` function object gets a `name` property set to "getX".

---

> But what causes confusion is that `this` of the (first) `getX` will also reference the pointer calling the (first) `getX` function.

The `this` value seen by code inside a function is generally determined **at run time** by the JavaScript engine (at compile time for arrow functions), and provided in scope chain records of the function when called - meaning `this` is **NOT** passed to the function as an argument.  Hence the first call to `getX`

```
module.getX()
```

is compiled into

- get the value of `module`
- call `getX` and pass it `module` as its `this` value.

  > *Moved from comment*:
  > Using extra words, when executing `module.getX()`, a `this` value of `module` is passed to `getX` in its environment records, not as an argument.

and

`var getX = module.getX`

creates a global variable called `getX` and sets its value to the  function object reference held in `module.getX`. When the global variable `getX` is called, the run time engine passes the global object as the `this` value seen by `getX` when it runs.

---

> When I define the second (pointer to) function by `var getX = module.getX`, it helps us to keep seeing the first getX inside/of module.

Only in the sense of looking at the initializer for `module` to see the source code of `getX`. The global variable points to a function object named `getX` *and* `module.getX` independently points to the same function object. However, modifying values of `module.getX` and `var getX` don't affect each other.

---

**See Also**

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for researching web development in general,
- [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) reference on MDN,
- [Inferred Function Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#inferred_function_names) on MDN,
- Related question [Why do anonymous function in JavaScript have names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45147093/5217142).